# CarrierWaveで画像が保存できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

現在CarrirWaveを用いて画像をアップロードする機能を作っているのですが、
どうしても画像がDBに格納されません。。
是非とも皆様の知恵をお借りできれば幸いです。

パラメーターには画像名が入っているのですが、@projectには格納されていない状態なためDBには保存されておりません。

```
Started POST "/admin/project/complete" for ::1 at 2021-01-29 03:55:34 +0900
Processing by ProjectsController#complete as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PW/4od6USTkRYA/WejU0IdrzwYUOwnJa4D8B8X7Ucq0EouC3d3FtWIzw4cpRl+fMYnPcROrHs8zyEykNIwi7rg==", "project"=>{"page_title"=>"test", "page_description"=>"test", "category_id"=>"1", "image"=>"/uploads/tmp/1611860130-792812304018408-0001-1745/4F24F1AA-6D96-4ECA-93B2-517767B400CE.JPG", "contents"=>"<p>test</p>"}, "commit"=>"内容を確認する >"}

From: /test-app/app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:24 ProjectsController#complete:

    22: def complete
    23:   @project = Project.new(project_params)
 => 24:   binding.pry
    25:   if @project.save!
    26:     redirect_to :action => 'admin_index'
    27:   else
    28:     render :action => 'new'
    29:   end
    30: end

[1] pry(#<ProjectsController>)> @project
=> #<Project:0x00007fdee0a3e640
 id: nil,
 page_title: "test",
 page_description: "test",
 category_id: 1,
 image: nil,
 contents: "<p>test</p>",
 author_user_id: nil,
 last_update_user_id: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>
```

なお、public/uploads/tmpへは保存されております。

そのまま処理を進めると、やはりDBに格納する直前でバリデーションがかかります。

```
Started POST "/admin/project/complete" for ::1 at 2021-01-29 04:52:18 +0900
Processing by ProjectsController#complete as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Bl4b0y0RxyelZ4+fe+rF81IuJxjgB0uw3NROpcyJEnM/kwPFhPTjRjj3YYNQSBYe6q462QQCiibO+GZZkVXbcA==", "project"=>{"page_title"=>"wet", "page_description"=>"wet", "category_id"=>"1", "image"=>"/uploads/tmp/1611863536-108188832449489-0007-9172/4F24F1AA-6D96-4ECA-93B2-517767B400CE.JPG", "contents"=>"<p>qwet</p>"}, "commit"=>"内容を確認する >"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:24
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:24
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (バリデーションに失敗しました: Imageを入力してください):

app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:24:in `complete'
```

#### 該当のソースコード

**view/project/new.html.haml**

```
- provide(:page_title, 'PROJECT 新規作成')

.adminCommonContainer
  = simple_form_for @project, url: admin_project_confirm_path, html: {multipart: true} do |f|
    .inputField
      = f.input :page_title, label: "タイトル", error: false
    .inputField
      = f.input :page_description, label: "ディスクリプション", error: false
    .inputField
      = f.input :category_id, as: :select, collection: [ ['Workshop', 1], ['Conference', 2] ], label: "カテゴリー", error: false
    .inputField
      = f.file_field :image, label: "サムネ写真", error: false
      = f.hidden_field :image_cache
    .inputField
      = f.text_area :contents, label: "コンテンツ", error: false, class: "project_contents"
    .submitButton
      = f.submit '内容を確認する >', class: 'link__box'
```

**controller/project_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  
  def admin_index
    @projects = Project.all.order('created_at DESC')
    render :layout => 'admin_application'
  end
  def new
    @project = Project.new
    render :layout => 'admin_application'
  end
  def confirm
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    render :layout => 'admin_application'
  end
  def complete
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    binding.pry
    if @project.save!
      redirect_to :action => 'admin_index'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:page_title, :page_description, :category_id, :image, :image_cache, :contents, :author_user_id, :last_update_user_id)
  end
end
```

**model/project.rb**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates :page_title, presence: true
  validates :page_description, presence: true
  validates :category_id, presence: true
  validates :image, presence: true
  validates :contents, presence: true
end
```

**uploaders/image_uploader.rb**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    # コメントアウト部省略

  storage :file

    # コメントアウト部省略

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # コメントアウト部省略
end
```

**db/schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_01_28_165336) do
  create_table "projects", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "page_title"
    t.text "page_description"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.string "image"
    t.text "contents"
    t.integer "author_user_id"
    t.integer "last_update_user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

```
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin19]
rails 5.2.4.4
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.32, for osx10.15 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
carrierwave (2.1.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
new（作成） → confirm（確認） → complete（完了）と言った形で確認画面を挟んでいたのですが、その際、cacheの設定をしていなかったため、confirmからcompleteにいく際に画像がない状態になっていたようです。
viewとcontrollerを下記にように変更しました。

#### veiw

**BEFORE: view/project/confirm.html.haml**

```
　　#省略
 　.inputField
    = f.input :image, as: :hidden,  label: "サムネ画像", error: false
    = @project.image
　　#省略
```

**AFTER: view/project/confirm.html.haml**

```
　　#省略
 　.inputField
  　= image_tag(@project.image.url)#ここを変更
  　= hidden_field_tag :"cache[image]", @project.image.cache_name #ここを変更
　　#省略
```

#### controller

**BEFORE: controller/project_controller.rb**

```
　　#省略
  def complete
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save!
      redirect_to :action => 'admin_index'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
　　#省略
```

**AFTER: controller/project_controller.rb**

```
　　#省略
  def complete
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    @project.image.retrieve_from_cache! params[:cache][:image] #これを追加
    if @project.save!
      redirect_to :action => 'admin_index'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
　　#省略
```